# Migrating from prototype to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, migration, prototypejs

I am migrating my js lib from prototype to jquery. However, I don't know how to replace the following code:

```
var utilityMethods = {     
        autoHide : function(element) {
               //...
}

Element.addMethods('SPAN', utilityMethods);
```

Is there a jQuery equivalent for extending the DOM?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You extend JQuery objects like so:

```
var utilityMethods = {     
    autoHide : function(element) {
           //...
    }
};

jQuery.fn.extend(utilityMethods);
```

More info: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.extend

Answer (score 1):

Actually, jQuery specifically avoids extending the DOM. Having recently completed a migration from Prototype to jQuery, this was one of the selling points for me. Instead, you [extend jQuery itself](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). Selecting a DOM object with jQuery gives you a jQuery object that contains a reference to one or more DOM objects. Any method calls on the jQuery object (including your custom utility methods) operate on the DOM elements referenced by that jQuery object.