# Strategies to migrate from Prototype to jQuery (Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I have an existing Rails App with considerable `js` code written using **Prototype**, I would like to make **jQuery** the default app's javascript framework and then migrate the existing **Prototype** code the **jQuery**'s equivalent.

What is your experience with this kind of issues or what strategies you suggest me in order to make this as painless as possible :P.

Any help would be appreciate, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Dear god, write tests for the code first. It's less that you'll thank yourself for doing so later - more that you'll really really wish you had if you don't. Try QUnit if you'd like to test the js directly, and Selenium if you want to test using the browser itself.

Comment: Here are some more places to research, as well.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512099/migrating-from-prototype-to-jquery

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134572/jquery-prototype-conflict

Comment: Thanks, Actually we write test for controllers/models but nothing of `js` :'(, this a good point to start writing `js` tests :P.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below link -

http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.com/2008/09/migrating-to-jquery.html